# How to perform conditional back navigation using Navigation Components?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have a destination fragment called "C" that can be navigated to by using one of 3 different flows.

E.g.

Flow 1: A -> C

Flow 2: A -> B -> C

Flow 3: A -> X -> Y -> C

I'm using global actions to navigate to C because it allows me to use the same action for navigation regardless of if I'm in Flow 1, 2 or 3. That all seems to work fine, but I'm having trouble with navigating back from C now.

For Flows 1 and 2 I want to go from C back to A. I've been doing this by calling `.popBackStack(R.id.A, false)` which was worked well. Now we've added Flow 3 to our app. In Flow 3,  when I navigate back from C I want to go to X, not A. So my previous solution of using `.popBackStack(R.id.A, false)` does not work here since this will always bring me back to A.

Is there a recommended way of providing back navigation that is conditional upon how the user got to the destination they're currently at?

I could see examining the existing back stack and if I see X or Y, then I'd know to use `.popBackStack(R.id.x, false).` or `.popBackStack(R.id.a, false)`.

I could pass in a "back ID" as an argument when launching C which I could then use in `.popBackStack(backId, false)`

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Does adding another `<action>` to fragment `C` in your `navGraph` is a possible option?

Comment: @BenShmuel I could add two different actions, one bringing me back to A, the other bringing me back to X, however, I'd still need to add some logic to figure out which action to use. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The action that pops back to `X` should be called only from inside of fragment `Y`, for example if that is a button in fragment `Y` the `onClick` should launch this action.